# How do you write CSS in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a div to rotate when the cursor is over it. I'm not sure at all how to do this, and every search I have tried leads to an unintelligible list of modules I don't have installed and don't want to take the extra time to install if I may never need it again. I think `document.write` or `document.writeIn` should work but it didn't when I tried to use it. In short, how do you change a specific CSS attribute (`rotate`) in jQuery/javascript?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/
check this out!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 5):

> when the cursor is over it

So you want the `:hover` psuedo-class:

```css
.mydiv:hover {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    /* adjust angle as desired */
}
```

Maybe you want it so transition smoothly?

```css
.mydiv { /* note: no :hover here */
    transition: transform 0.8s ease;
}
```

Plain CSS is a powerful tool. Use it well.

Comment: Don't forget to name all the CSS prefixes `-webkit-` `-moz-` `-ms-` `-o-` (i.e.: `-webkit-transition: rotate(45deg); -moz-transition: rotate(45deg); /*... until set them all */`)

Comment: `transition` is fully supported in all browsers, and `transform` only has `-webkit-transform`. So `-webkit-transform` is the only one you need.

Comment: Really? oh, everyday i learn something new, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not in css? It's better in performance.

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: limegreen;
    transition: transform 1s;
}
div:hover{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

And the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mn25C/1/). This is probaly even easier than jQuery.

Comment: I added Chrome and FF support to your fiddle :)

Comment: Thanks. I just editted it myself :P Did it again to keep your fiddle. BTW, it was working in FF, most FF-users are up to date

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

```
element.style.yourAttributeHere = value
```

But again, I'd always take the CSS road if I could and use JS only for something CSS can't handle.

Comment: Yay, a downvote, can't wait to hear.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but your answer sounds more like a comment.

Comment: @RayCheng I wouldn't mind if it was you (I'm not a revenge downvoter). But the code part of my answer is how you apply CSS styles in JS and it directly answers the question...and the second line does look like a comment, agreed, because the other answers showed the CSS approach, so there was no need to duplicate them.

Comment: Agree your first line is code, but I'm afraid it has too little details for OP to take on. I could be wrong about OP, but I was expecting more details. However your comments are great to OP where other answers lack of. Worth a up vote!

Comment: Your question answers the title of the question, not the question itself.  It's short, lacks explanation and provides the O.P. no direct insight on how to actually solve the problem he's facing.

Comment: @Axel "In short, how do you change a specific CSS attribute (rotate) in jQuery/javascript?" "element.style.yourAttributeHere = value" If someone needs additional explanation for this, then they should probably consider other professions. I mean, I surely could write a novel about what the element is, what style is, list all the attributes... maybe history of JavaScript, but the answer to the question (not just the title) would remain the same. Try answering this with a long, explanatory answer: "What time it is?"

Comment: Sorry, but I find your attitude on the subject rather immature.  Yes it may be common sense to you, but the whole purpose of Stackoverflow isn't just to answer the question as quickly and basically as possible, it's to also help others learn from your own experience.  Maybe you're answering questions for the wrong reasons, who knows.  I feel like the community deserves well thought out, detailed answers along with an explanation on the subject.  Contribute to the quality of the community, not the quantity of short, fast answers.

Comment: So the quality of community is based on the word quantity of each answer (to make them high-quality answers)? Anyway, bear in mind that SO is meant to be a knowledge base, not a forum, not a manual and definitely not a code-sharing website. So when I search for "how to do X?" (X being something very specific), I'd appreciate getting a brief and accurate answer. And I boldly assume majority of people would do so, too. You might not be one of them and that's fine, but you stated false arguments in your original comment. Have a nice day and thanks for the attitude assessment. @Axel

Comment: My arguments aren't false, that's your own opinion.  I personally feel that your answer is inadequate to the question being asked and rightly so I left feedback with a downvote.  Again to recap, it answers the generality of the question, but not the question itself.  We have a difference in opinion which is fine, I'll leave it at that.